# Request entity too large on .NET ASMX Web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json, iis-7, asmx

I have developed a .NET Web Service using C# and I have it running on IIS7. The web service is being consumed by a Blackberry app.

The web service in general returns about 2,000 and 3,000 records the first time that it runs, it then downloads this information to the Blackberry and is cached there so that I don't have to download again.

The response is a JSON string

The typical service response is about 150 Kb but there are a couple of cases in which the web service returns between 3,000 and 4,000 records (which would be around 200 Kb, that's the top records case), in those cases the web service is returning a "Request Entity Too Large" message.

This doesn't make any sense because the request is 38 bytes long (just a few chars) and it's almost the same request as with the other cases that work great.

I already searched some information about it on the Internet but I haven't been able to fix it.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens if you send back 500 records instead? Just for kicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blackberry Enterprise server still limits responses to a preset value and will return a "413 request entity is too large" message.

My opinion is that you will need to limit the service and return smaller but multiple replies.

Comment: Hi Mike, this Blackberry is not running on BES but on BIS, do you think it would still have this same limitation with BIS? I have the same problem with the simulator,

Comment: I think so, this should help you out http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Getting-HTTP-Error-413-request-entity-too-large-in-BES/td-p/295166  - I think the last comment also applies to you.

Comment: Thanks Mike!, looks like the problem was under with the simulator, shekhaman's answer on the BB forums saved my day.

Comment: Excellent, make sure you check your production environment as changing a clients BES setup won't be as straightforward and quick.